# SC2 camera positioning easy way?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am new to StarCraft 2. I got to understand that we can position cameras from <kbd>F5</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> buttons. It means only 4 buttons. But what if I want to use camera positions more than 4 positions?

Is there an easy way by adding camera positions to some hot key and then by pressing tab key we can navigate those positions? Is this possible? If not, how do the pros usually setup their camera positions?

And also seeming tough to remember the camera positions too. I don't like to use many hotkeys just to switch camera positions.

Comment: I belive there should be 8-10 positions available. Look at options hotkey setup. They are like shift-fx probably and you can change this.

Comment: About pros's hotkeysetup you can watch this video: http://day9.tv/d/Day9/day9-daily-252-secrets-of-hotkeys-apm-and-mouse-movement/

Comment: Hi @JohnG - I've removed your second question about Hamachi. If you have multiple unrelated questions, ask them as separate question :)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an easy way by adding camera positions to some hot key and then by pressing tab key we can navigate those positions? Is this possible?

**No, it is not possible.**

You really need to use different keys per each location.

Personally, I use only 4 locations, 1 per each of the first 4 bases.

- Main base - F1
- Second base - F2
- Third base - F3
- Fourth base - F4

I bind them using `Ctrl+F1..F4` and just go on them clicking on `F1..F4`.

I'm sure that if you make some practice you'll find that really easy.

> But what if I want to use camera positions more than 4 positions?

**Yes, you can use more than 4 camera positions**

Just bind them to other keys you are not using. In my personal case, If needed, I would bind them from `F5..F8`.

> How to bind Camera Positions?

**Follow these easy steps:**

1. Click `F10` to access the Menu
2. Click on `Options`
3. Click on `Hotkeys`
4. Select your profile
5. Click on `Global`
6. Click on `Camera`
7. Go to `Create Location 1..10`
8. Add your new binding sequence
9. Go to `Jump to location 1..10`
10. Add your new location calling key
11. Save

> How do the pros usually setup their camera positions?

**Pros use settings close to mine if they are Protoss/Terran. While, some Zergs, just jump from a base to another using `Base Camera.`**

> What about `F2`? If I bind `F2` to `Jump on second Location`, how can I select my whole army?

**You just bind `Select Army Units` to another key like `Q` or another key**

Personally, I play Protoss and I stopped using F2 since I was Silver (Now I'm Master from lots of seasons). I stopped because it also selects units on hold positions, observers, flying units (e.g. Phoenixes) and caster units (e.g. High Templars) that I don't really want to bring with the main army.

I hope I've been helpfull, GL & HF.

Comment: Thank you, you are right on the first one, I'll fix that.

Comment: I find F2-ctrl-select-unit-type to be incredibly useful. One must just **never** get into the habit of F2-moving, as you rightly pointed out.